# Weird issue during calling the object's method in python - 'self' pointing to the wrong object?

Tags: python, class, object, inheritance, methods

I found some weird behaviour during the creation of classes and objects in python3.

I dislike typing every time "self" word and constructors during writing classes if my class is very simple so I made the class 'Foo' that copies static variables and turns them into the new object's attributes.

At the beginning I was making 'Foo' subclasses without methods and then everything worked fine - the objects were distinct. However, after adding a method to the subclass, I found out that the self value somehow points to wrong object.

Here is the code I made:

```
from copy import deepcopy


class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        for i in filter(lambda x: "__" not in x, self.__dir__()):
            self.__setattr__(i, deepcopy(self.__getattribute__(i)))


class Bar(Foo):
    val = []

    def func(self):
        print("Self ID:", id(self))
        print(self.val)


obj = Bar()
obj.val.append(2)
print("Object ID:", id(obj))
print(obj.val)
obj.func()

# Prints:
#
# Object ID: 2507794284496
# [2]
# Self ID: 2507794283248
# []
#
# While it should print same ID and [2] in both lists
```

I am sure that I forgot something important during creation of the Foo class because if I remove "(Foo)" part then IDs and the lists are the same.

Could someone explain me what is wrong? Thank you in advance for help! <3

Comment: can you try create `__init__(self)` method in child class add `super(self)` method inside **init** child method ?

Comment: Already tried that - but didn't help

Comment: I get TypeError: super() argument 1 must be type, not Bar

Comment: If i do instead super().__init__() then no error but doesn't help

Comment: The child class doesn't define `__init__`, so it inherits that method from the parent.

Comment: Why don't you just use a dataclass?

Comment: deepcopy is the cause.  If you call `self.__setattr__(i, self.__getattribute__(i))` without the deepcopy, it prints the same id and val.

Comment: @pavel I didn't know of its existence, it can help yes! Thank you for your advice. Gave upvote :) But still being curious what is going wrong in here. Just for learning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I disabled methods from copying and it seems working now.
Here is the code:

```
from copy import deepcopy


class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        for i in filter(lambda x: "__" not in x, self.__dir__()):
            attr = self.__getattribute__(i)
            if attr.__class__.__name__ != 'method':
                self.__setattr__(i, deepcopy(attr))


class Bar(Foo):
    val = []

    def func(self):
        print("Self ID:", id(self))
        print(self.val)


obj = Bar()
obj.val.append(2)
print("Object ID:", id(obj))
print(obj.val)
obj.func()

# Object ID: 2785572945632
# [2]
# Self ID: 2785572945632
# [2]
```

I don't see any usecase where copying the method would be necessary so it's not an issue really for me.

Great thanks @user2357112 for explaining me what was not working <3

Comment: This works around one kind of thing you don't want to copy, but then if you want to add `@property` support, now you have to add another awkward special case, and that one's even more awkward than special-casing methods. If you want one of your classes to have a `@classmethod`, that takes more awkward special-casing. If you want one of your classes to have an actual class variable, things get *really* awkward. There are enough headaches that this kind of approach quickly becomes more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: of course! i don't plan to use Foo class for all my uses - just for simple classes like class Person (so attributes like address, list of kids, age, and so on)

Answer (score 3):

You're retrieving a `self.func` method object, deep copying it, and assigning the result to `self.func`.

The deep copy creates a method object bound to a new `Bar` instance, which will have its own copies of any instance attributes created before the method was copied, and no instance attribute for any instance attributes that would have been created after the method was copied. Either way, it's the wrong instance with the wrong attributes.

Comment: I understand! So my only option is using here dataclass? I can not copy static variables manually?

Comment: @AmaeSaeki: I would recommend just writing the `__init__` methods you don't want to write. Dataclasses are an available option, but the dataclass system does a lot of stuff by default that may not be appropriate for your use case, plus you'll have to be careful about stuff like `default_factory` for mutable defaults.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
class Bar(Foo):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(self)
        self.val = []

    def func(self):
        print("Self ID:", id(self))
        print(self.val)
```

should it works.

```
Object ID: 140516181578944
[2]
Self ID: 140516181578944
[2]
```

Comment: This doesn't solve anything  - it overwrites init method so inheriting Foo makes no sense here

Comment: If i wanted it to work i can simply remove (Foo) and have same effect - I want to understand while copying attributes makes self pointing to wrong object durting inheriting from Foo

Comment: i think the problem is in **val** state, when you initiate object all state must be inside __init__ method.